# Linus Pauling, General Chemistry 1-2 - Does Light has mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

Linus Pauling, General Chemistry 1-2:

> "...it was pointed out by Einstein that energy also has a mass, and
> that light is accordingly attracted to matter by gravitation."

Isn't that wrong? It is curved by the fact that spacetime itself curves.

> "1-2. Mass and Energy
>
> Matter has mass, and any portion of matter on the earth is attracted
> toward the center of the earth by the force of gravity; this
> attraction is called the weight of the portion of matter. For many
> years scientists thought that matter and radiant energy could be
> distinguished through the possession of mass by matter and the lack of
> possession of mass by energy. Then, early in the present century
> (1905), it was pointed out by Albert Einstein (1879-1955) that energy
> also has mass, and that light is ac- cordingly attracted by matter
> through gravitation. This was verified by astronomers, who found that
> a ray of light traveling from a distant star to the earth and passing
> close by the sun is bent toward the sun by its gravi- tational
> attraction. The observation of this phenomenon was made during a solar
> eclipse, when the image of the star could be seen close to the sun.
> The amount of mass associated with a definite amount of energy given
> by an important equation, the Einstein equation, which is an essen-
> tial part of the theory of relativity: E= mc² (1-1) In this equation E
> is the amount of energy (J), m is the mass (kg), and c is the velocity
> of light (m s-1).* The velocity of light, c, is one of the funda-
> mental constants of nature;t its value is 2.9979 X 10 meters per
> second."

So one can rather say that spacetime curvature is not a causal explanation for gravity. It's just a geometric analogy? Does what Linus Pauling writes then make sense again? He has somehow a Newtonian way of looking.

Comment: He's just using "massive" to mean "able to have its path affected by gravity". By that definition everything is massive. But by modern definitions, light is not.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the first quote is formulated really badly and a little bit wrong but not completely, as like you said the path light takes is due to the curvature of spacetime;
Spacetime curvature isn't an analogy, in Einsteins formulation of general relativity spacetime curves due to energy being present, we can see this in the field equation:
$R_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu \nu}=\kappa T_{\mu \nu}$
here $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor (to which all the present mass but $\textbf{also light}$ contributes as it has energy). This equation then locks up the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ (The metric captures all the geometric and causal structure of spacetime, i.e the curvature) from which we can calculate the christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{c a b}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial g_{c a}}{\partial x^{b}}+\frac{\partial g_{c b}}{\partial x^{a}}-\frac{\partial g_{a b}}{\partial x^{c}}\right)$ ultimately giving us the possibility to determine the geodesic $\frac{d^{2} x^{\mu}}{d s^{2}}+\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} \frac{d x^{\alpha}}{d s} \frac{d x^{\beta}}{d s}=0$ of the particle (e.g light) we're investigating. This geodesic is essentially how the is particle moving in a straight line on curved spacetime.
So to concretely answer your question, spacetime does curve and light follows this curvature but light also contributes to this curvature via the energy-momentum tensor.

Comment: Light curving spacetime is true of course. But it's harder to measure and not what Pauling was talking about.